# Python type error issue TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Table' and 'float'

Tags: python

I got a table with some IMDB movies (movie name, rating, year). I want to calculate the average rating for all movies in the 20th century and the 21st century.

```
table_20th = imdb.where("Year",are.below(2000))
table_21th = imdb.where("Year",are.above_or_equal_to(2000))


rating_20th = table_20th.select("Rating")
rating_21th = table_21th.select("Rating")


average_20th_century_rating = float(np.average(rating_20th.column(0)))
average_21th_century_rating = float(np.average(rating_21th.column(0)))


print("Type 20th", type(average_20th_century_rating))
print("Type 21st", type(average_21th_century_rating))

print("Average 20th century rating:", average_20th_century_rating)
print("Average 21st century rating:", average_21st_century_rating)

print(abs(average_20th_century_rating - 8.2783625730994146) < 1e-5)
print(abs(average_21st_century_rating - 8.2379746835443033) < 1e-5)
```

The abs() of the 20th century movie works but the abs of the 21st century movie throws a type error. But all abs() arguments are floats.

The following output is produced

```
Type 20th <class 'float'>
Type 21st <class 'float'>
Average 20th century rating: 8.278362573099415
Average 21st century rating: Rating
8.23797
True

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-136-bc0060cc4666> in <module>()
     20 
     21 print(abs(average_20th_century_rating - 8.2783625730994146) < 1e-5)
---> 22 print(abs(average_21st_century_rating - 8.2379746835443033) < 1e-5)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Table' and 'float'
```

Could somebody give me a hint please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your last two usages of `average_21th_century_rating`. They are wrongly written as `average_21st_century_rating` which is definitely not a float, rather a class of type `Rating`.